# How can I find mean and covariance after EM iteration on GMM algorithmm?

Tags: expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a dataset divided in 2 class(lets call x1,x2) but I don't know their mean and covariance.

For each class I looked their graph and made a guess about their sub-classes, then run an EM(Expectation-Maximization) algorithm to them one by one to find these inner classes  mean and covairance. So now i have something like this:
if sub-class k= 2 for x1

- x1_1mean
- x1_2mean
- x1_1cov
- x1_2cov
- x1_1alfa
- x1_2alfa

After that point how can I calculate the actual class mean and covariance from these sub-classes to test its performance on dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop, gives detailed steps for implementing EM for Gaussian mixture models.

[image: EM-GMM]

Using the steps given here, it should be easy to implement.