# How to make a GMM from a Histogram to give a probability?

Tags: density-function, histogram, generalized-moments

I have a histogram that looks like the following:

[image: Histogram]

From the data, I can see that this histogram shows two obvious curves. If I make the claim that they are from two Gaussians, how can I make a Gaussian mixture model to tell me the probabilities of an unseen `x`.

Is it possible to "`learn`" where the two Gaussian are in this histogram?
After which, what is the accepted methodology for getting a probability from the GMM?

Comment: The EM algorithm does precisely what you want. Check out this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268895/how-can-i-find-mean-and-covariance-after-em-iteration-on-gmm-algorithmm/270834#270834).

Comment: Yes, but EM is usually for multidimensional inputs. My data is just a list of values which have this obvious gmm like shape after viewing them in a histogram.  I'm having a hard time understanding how a list of values could be used in a GMM+EM framework.

Comment: EM can be used for both univariate and multivariate data. In your case you have univariate data i.e. the Gaussians have support over R. For instance consider the code given [here](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) it uses univariate data.

Comment: I will have to read more about EM to understand it thoroughly. I believe I have a misunderstanding about it fundamentally. I will also take a look at your links. It seems my question is reduced to: how do I model a GMM with univariate data? thank you @kedarps

Comment: @kedarps if you make an answer with EM I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you don't have to restrict yourself to mixtures of Gaussians. There might be other distributions that work better with this data and a finite mixture approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example is demonstrated using Matlab. It can be easily adapted into Python or R.

Let's assume that your data contains a mixture of two underlying Gaussians, $\mathcal{N}(m_1, s_1)$ and $\mathcal{N}(m_2, s_2)$. Now, let's generate some sample data.

```
% define mean and variances of two Gaussians
m1 = -5; s1 = 4;
m2 = 2; s2 = 1;

% Generate some sample data
X = [m1 + s1*randn(1000, 1); m2 + s2*randn(1000, 1)];
% plot a histogram
hist(X, 250);
```

This is a histogram of the data generated, which looks quite similar to the data you have:

[image: Histogram of generated data]

Now given $X$, let's try to estimate the Gaussian mixtures. In Matlab (> 2014a), the function [`fitgmdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitgmdist.html) estimates the Gaussian components using the EM algorithm.

```
% given X, fit a GMM with 2 components
gmm = fitgmdist(X, 2);
```

Here is a plot of the pdf of the estimated GMM, which very well matches the generated data:

[image: GMM distribution fit]

Here are the Gaussian parameters estimated by the EM algorithm, which are pretty close to the true values that were used to generate the data:

```
% estimated parameters
m1_est = gmm.mu(1); % = 2.0086
m2_est = gmm.mu(2); % = -5.3910

s1_est = sqrt(gmm.Sigma(:,:,1)); % = 1.0134
s2_est = sqrt(gmm.Sigma(:,:,2)); % = 3.8199
```

---

- For additional details on the EM algorithm, check [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268895/how-can-i-find-mean-and-covariance-after-em-iteration-on-gmm-algorithmm/270834#270834).
- For a similar example using Python, [see here](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html).